# Amazon S3 file upload with CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead Failed (Android)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to upload an image to an Amazon S3 bucket which is `PUBLIC` , which worked fine every time.

I tried setting the `CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead` property so that the uploaded image can be opened via browser.

When I set this property, not a single attempt to upload the image was successful. Every time I got `FAILED` status from the callback.

**My code:**

```
uploadObserver = uploadUtility.upload(
                AmazonConst.TELEPORT_BUCKET,     /* The bucket to upload to */
                key,    /* The key for the uploaded object */
                fileModel.getFile(), /* The file where the data to upload exists */
                CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead /* Specify PublicRead ACL for the object in the bucket. */
        );
```

Comment: Are you saying that **upload** failed, or that you were unable to **download** the file once it was uploaded using this code? When you say "not a single attempt to upload the image was successful", what error message did you receive? Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: I am now trying only image upload. As I mentioned in my question I just receive FAILED from TransferState object

Comment: What version of SDK are you using?